summarise not getting expected result?
For the following code:
d <- data.frame(seq=c(0,0,1,1,2,2,2),
            kdt=c('2023-01-30','2023-01-30','2023-04-04','2023-04-04','2023-06-01',
                  '2023-06-04','2023-   06-04'),
            ldt=c('2023-01-30','2023-01-30','2023-04-04','2023-04-04','2023-06-01',NA,NA),
            l=c(11,15,22,17,NA,34,22),
            r=c('A','A','B','B','C',NA,NA))

ds <- d %>% 
   group_by(seq) %>% 
   summarise(mkdt=max(kdt),mldt=max(ldt),sl=sum(l),mr=max(r))

I was expecting the mldt='2023-06-01', mr='C' and sl=56 for seq=2 row, but all 3 are showing NA, am I missing something?

You need to pass na.rm = TRUE to the function's in summarize.
d <- data.frame(seq=c(0,0,1,1,2,2,2),
                kdt=c('2023-01-30','2023-01-30','2023-04-04','2023-04-04','2023-06-01',
                      '2023-06-04','2023-   06-04'),
                ldt=c('2023-01-30','2023-01-30','2023-04-04','2023-04-04','2023-06-01',NA,NA),
                l=c(11,15,22,17,NA,34,22),
                r=c('A','A','B','B','C',NA,NA))
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(seq) %>% 
  summarise(mkdt=max(kdt, na.rm = T),mldt=max(ldt, na.rm = T),sl=sum(l, na.rm = T),mr=max(r, na.rm = T))


Thanks! I knew this should be something simple :-(
